# Wikitude I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: World is not defined"

Tags: android, wikitude, wikitude-sdk

I am getting `I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: World is not defined"`in Wikitude 7.0.0 for Sumsung tablet only.

Find the log

> 04-30 15:20:07.886 604-2171/? E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
>       java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
>           at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:15037)
>           at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:2492)
>           at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.call(SettingsProvider.java:688)
>           at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:325)
>           at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:275)
>           at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
>           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
>   04-30 15:20:07.886 18411-18411/com.itc.classmate I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: World is not defined", source: file:///android_asset/selfi/selfi_1/ (1)
>   04-30 15:20:07.886 604-2171/? W/ActivityManager: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
>   04-30 15:20:07.946 148-18583/? D/ShotSingle: CAMERA_MSG_PREVIEW_FRAME E
>   04-30 15:20:07.946 604-2170/? I/EDMNativeHelperService: isCameraEnabled
>   04-30 15:20:07.946 148-18583/? D/ShotSingle: CAMERA_MSG_PREVIEW_FRAME X

Comment: That would indicate an issue in your JS code but without any code it is hard to guess what is wrong, so please provide the code causing this issue.

Comment: Issue is coming from Wikitude.... Code is fine. It is working with mobiles not with tablet

Comment: Since there is no "World" object in the Wikitude SDK it seems to be an issue of the Application. (World is only used in the samples.)

Comment: Thanks for reply. Let me confirm.

Comment: @Alex, I updated the log. Can you please check and tell me the root cause of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, `Uncaught ReferenceError: World is not defined`
Most probably issue with JS where you defined World ref. Just check that code and find the syntax error/comment the unnecessary code. Definitively it will work.